# Bootstrap 3 vs. Bootstrap 2 nesting columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using a 16 column grid. In BS2, we were able to use 4 columns for our left-hand nav and nest the remaining 12 for our main content area. (Which was really convenient for all the reasons 12 is nice.)

In BS3 a nested zone inherits the full number of columns so we are struggling to figure out how to adapt our designs from an assumed 12 to 16 in the content area. (No longer can divide by 3.)

In an ideal world we would just have used 12 columns from the beginning and all would be right in the world. However, the designer wanted finer-grained control which in BS2 16 cols worked well.

Is there some way to set a different column count for a nested area in BS3? Or, are we screwed and should just rework all templates, etc. to a 12 column grid? We could force the issue by setting percentage widths but that is rather distasteful and I would like to work within the framework instead.

Edit - We're just going to throw in the towel and change to 12 grid system using BS3 and not fight the general design of the framework. Thanks for your feedback everyone!

Comment: are you sure?bs2 supports 16cols?http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Why don't you not use Bootstrap columns and use: http://goldengridsystem.com/

Comment: Bootstrap has a 12 column layout. Period. How are you using 16 without nesting?

Comment: @Ranveer - In BS2 there are configuration variables to set the number of columns. 3.0 dropped that but the latest version of 3 allows you too choose your column count again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Could your original BS2 be using nested grids?
4 columns for the left hand nav and 8 for the content, then nested within the content another row/container that would have another 12 columns for your primary content?

I believe in the example below, the nested section gets all 12 columns.
Is that what your after?
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: You are right that nesting gets the full column count now. It wasn't like that in BS2 which is why we could do 4 then 12. With the new one, we had 4 then 16 which was a problem. We're just going to change all the designs over to a 12. Fortunately, since the designer was the same guy who designed for BS2, his assumptions on columns will map pretty close to a 12 on BS3 vs. 16 on BS2 the way it nests now.

Answer (score 0):

Not a true answer but marking it as an answer to prevent this question from coming up unanswered anymore... we're just going to switch to a 12 column layout for BS3.